# How to validate the response body with special characters using rest-assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm developing an API automation test, the API response is:

```
"Se você é um usuário registrado, receberá um e-mail para recuperação de senha."
```

but when I try to get it using the follow code:

```
        public void responseBodyResetSenha (String srtMensagem) {
            String responseMensagem = ResponseHolder.getResponseBody();
            System.out.println(responseMensagem);
            Assert.assertEquals(responseMensagem, srtMensagem);
```

The response that I receive is:

```
"Se voc\u00ea \u00e9 um usu\u00e1rio registrado, receber\u00e1 um e-mail para recupera\u00e7\u00e3o de senha."
```

There is a way to get it right? Thanks

Comment: Maybe, the cause of this problem is incorrect encoding. Try to explicitly specify encoding when you get response body (i'm not sure if there is such overloaded method)

Comment: That response is correct.  In Java, `\u00ea` is an alternative “escape syntax” for the `ê` character.  More generally, `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits represents the character with that number as its codepoint.  You haven’t said how you’re viewing the response, but I suspect it can be adjusted to show non-ASCII characters without escaping them.

Comment: Please, add your request